# Disable global scope on model show?

Tags: laravel

I have a model called project which can be archived. Archived projects do not show on the index page and I do that by using global scope on the Project model:

```
class ArchiveScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('archived', false);
    }
}
```

then within the Project model, I have:

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ArchiveScope);
    }
```

However, I have a page where I'm showing all archived projects and users should be able to click on each project, view the content, and un-archive the project if needed. But due to the global scope, it will not display the project. When I go to an archived project at /projects/{project_id}, it gives me 404 not found error. How can I apply withoutGlobalScope to the show operation of Project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it

```
Project::withoutGlobalScope(ArchiveScope::class)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is your thing: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

If you want to remove all of the global scopes:

```
Model::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();
```

Or if you want to remove some of them:

```
Model::withoutGlobalScopes([
    Model1::class, Model2::class, etc...
])->get();
```

In your case you can just write:

```
Project::withoutGlobalScope(ArchiveScope::class)->get();
```